# Is it possible to define Omega combinator (λx.xx) in modern Haskell?

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

Stack! Is it possible to define Omega combinator (λx.xx) in modern Haskell? I suppose, Haskell98's type system is designed to make things like this impossible, but what about modern extensions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, but sort of.  The thing to appreciate here is that Haskell supports unrestricted recursion in `newtype` declarations.  By the semantics of Haskell, a `newtype` is an isomorphism between the type being defined and its implementation type.  So for example this definition:

```
newtype Identity a = Identity { runIdentity :: a }
```

...asserts that the types `Identity a` and `a` are isomorphic.  The constructor `Identity :: a -> Identity a` and the observer `runIdentity :: Identity a -> a` are inverses, by definition.

So borrowing the `Scott` type name from svenningsson's answer, the following definition:

```
newtype Scott = Scott { apply :: Scott -> Scott }
```

...asserts that the type `Scott` is isomorphic to `Scott -> Scott`.  So you while you can't apply a `Scott` to itself directly, you can use the isomorphism to obtain its `Scott -> Scott` counterpart and apply that to the original:

```
omega :: Scott -> Scott
omega x = apply x x
```

Or slightly more interesting:

```
omega' :: (Scott -> Scott) -> Scott
omega' f = f (Scott f)
```

...which is a fixpoint combinator type!  This trick can be adapted to write a version of the Y combinator in Haskell:

```
module Fix where

newtype Scott a = Scott { apply :: Scott a -> a }

-- | This version of 'fix' is fundamentally the Y combinator, but using the
-- 'Scott' type to get around Haskell's prohibition on self-application (see
-- the expression @apply x x@, which is @x@ applied to itself).  Example:
--
-- >>> take 15 $ fix ([1..10]++)
-- [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5]
fix :: (a -> a) -> a
fix f = (\x -> f (apply x x)) (Scott (\x -> f (apply x x)))
```

Answer (score 10):

You cannot represent omega directly in Haskell. There are very few typesystems that can represent self-applications and the type system of Haskell is not one of them. But you can encode the untyped lambda calculus and simulate omega and self application like so:

```
data Scott = Scott { apply :: Scott -> Scott }

omega = Scott $ \x -> apply x x
```

Now you can say `apply omega omega` and get a non-terminating computation. If you want to try it out in GHCi, you probably want the following `Show` instance

```
instance Show Scott where
  show (Scott _) = "Scott"
```

Comment: This kind of recursive types trigger a [GHC inliner bug](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/bugs.html#bugs-ghc) which prevents the optimizer to terminate on that, at compile time. Some `NOINLINE` pragma might be needed. (Using only GHCi it's easy to confuse non termination at compile time from run time).

Comment: @chi, GHCi doesn't inline anything.

Answer (score 6):

Well, you could define:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}

omega :: (forall a . a) -> b
omega x = x x
```

however this is pretty much useless, because the only value that can be passed as argument is `undefined`, so you cannot use it as a combinator at all. Even `omega omega` fails to type check.

The catch is that in order for `x x` to typecheck you'd have to type `x` with a type `T = t -> s` and where `t` unifies with `T` (so that you can pass `x` to itself). But this basically means that `t` must be a type variable and the argument must be fully polymorphic, rendering the function useless.

Comment: With this type signature `omega :: (forall a. a -> f a) -> f (a -> f a)` you can define `purePure :: Applicative f => f (a -> f a); purePure = omega pure`.